# handshake failure in ios push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to send a push notification to Ios device and here is my code,

```
 $ctx = stream_context_create();
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',
 ABSPATH.'apns-dev.pem');
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $password);


 $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', 
 $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,
 $ctx);

 if (!$fp)
      exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

 echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
 $payload = $message;
 foreach ($token as $deviceToken)
 {

 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
 }
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
 if (!$result)
     echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
 else
     echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;


 fclose($fp);
```

But I got errors like:

> 1. stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>      error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
> 2. stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
> 3. stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem and trying to resolve this problem from last few days. So did you find any solution for this issue?